# How to limit LTPA cookies to SSL only using jacl/jython

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin, jacl

When I am using the websphere console, and navigate to the Secure Administration -> SSO I have a checkbox called: 'Require SSL'. How do I enable/disable this using jacl/jython ?

I have even used the command assistance from the console. But when I checked the logs, I can see almost every other command being issues apart from this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jython:

```
AdminTask.configureSingleSignon('-requiresSSL true')
```

Other available options for the configureSingleSignon command:

```
-enable [true|false]
-domainName [String]
-interoperable [true|false]
-attributePropagation [true|false]
```

Reference: [SecurityConfigurationCommands command group for the AdminTask object](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rxml_7securityconfig.html).